# manipulating a string in R replacing decimals

Tags: r, stringr

i am a bit stuck on this problem. I am trying to delete the dots before the first number, but any dots between two numbers i would like to keep.

. . . . . . . . . . . . . . 122 (100.0) . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 7 (5. 7)

for example the above should output to

122 (100.0) . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 7 (5. 7)

I am not sure what functions or package i should be using to do the above

Thanks!

Comment: please provide a reproducible example. use `dput()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for what you're asking.

```
sub('^[\\h.]+', '', x, perl=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
#copy pasted from your example
text <- ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . 122 (100.0) . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 7 (5. 7)"

#find the location of the first number using gregexpr
loc <- gregexpr('[0-9]', text)[[1]][1]

#substring the text from loc and until the end
substr(text, loc, nchar(text)) # or substring(text, loc)
```

Output:

```
[1] "122 (100.0) . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 7 (5. 7)"
```